# Get an element inside two tags and looping through multiple variable

Tags: javascript

So I have a price that I get as a variable but I keep getting "USD 60" where I want just "60". After that I need to loop through multiple variables(price and quantity) then write two sentences. "An order was placed with a quantity of 2 and price of 60" "An order was placed with a quantity of 5 and price of 20." This is as close as can get it but the loop isn't working.
    
    
                2

```
</td>
<td class="v1_shop_cart_articles_col_qty">
            5
</td>
<td class="v1_shop_cart_articles_col_price"><span class="nobreak">USD <span>60.00</span></span></td>
<td class="v1_shop_cart_articles_col_price"><span class="nobreak">USD <span>20.00</span></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
var price = document.getElementsByClassName('v1_shop_cart_articles_col_price').getElementByTagName('span')[1].innerHTML;
var qty = document.getElementsByClassName('v1_shop_cart_articles_col_qty');


for(var i=0; i<qty.length; i++) {
    document.write('An order was placed with a quantity of '+
                    parseInt(qty[i].innerHTML, 10) + price +
                   '.'); 
    }
```

Comment: here is a codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CAask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hKafl

without a table, your td's weren't showing up - so your qty and price arrays were empty. also, when you were trying to get the price value, weren't accessing a specific element in the price array.